# Huge set of data, need to find top 10 most common from data set

Tags: excel

I have a huge set of data with which I need to find the top 10 most common occurrences - however there seems to be over 800 of each, and using the CountIf function I'd need to manually enter every single one.

Is there a quicker or more efficient way to do this?

CountIf, CountA, Filter

Comment: I would suggest you to start with this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

How is the data structured with rows/columns? I can think of a decently fast way but it would depend on the structure.

Comment: It's a raw data set pulled via csv; each individual entry (a purchase order) is listed on an individual row (there are 20,000+)

Comment: Could you copy the PO column to a new sheet, remove duplicates from it to get one unique PO Id each. Then do a COUNTIF formula on the original data set to get the total number of PO Ids for each Id. Then just sort highest to lowest and take the top ten?